# sending Data or Values to linked Objects in Blender 2.80 / 2.81

Tags: python, scripting, workflow, drivers, linked-data

I work a lot with linked data and library objects or linked collections.

Is it possible to send values or variables between the different hierachical structures ?

So for example:

- SCENEFILE (**var** = 1234)
- ---> Linked object 1 (pass_index + **var**)
- ---> Linked object 2 (locationX + **var**)

or to add a bit and be more precise:
If I have a gamma node for example inside a material in a linked Collection, how do I access these gamma node value and Control it from the MainStage ? can i use a Driver from the MainStage to Control these values inside linked objects?

OK - > I got a step further and can control a  value inside the linked Object.

linked objects can accessed via python as seen here in this Video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5M6cdhn4YCE

so

```
bpy.data.objects['Name_of_the_linked_obj'].pass_index
```

gives Access to the pass_index for example and can be set via python

```
bpy.data.objects['Name_of_the_linked_obj'].pass_index = 3
```

this is nice but not very comfortable or usable.
Now it would be great to have a way to control this datapath via Driver or Custom Property from the mainfile.

as you can see in the picture we can access this property in a Driver.
so I created a controller object that can drive this value and can override it.
but the data in the linked object does not change and

```
bpy.data.objects['Name_of_the_linked_obj'].pass_index = 3
```

is not evaluated

but when I use

```
bpy.data.objects['myCube'].pass_index = bpy.data.objects['Controller']['my_new_index']
```

it works immediatly...

here is the setup image
[image]

Comment: Maybe there is a Python solution that I can use ?